# How To Remove specific word from String?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to Remove (Apple Banana) from

String = 'I bought Apple , Banana , Orange and Mango'

NewString =  'I bought  ,  , Orange and Mango'

Comment: Have you tried with REPLACE?

Comment: google how to use the replace command, that is your best bet. also, post what you have tried and why it didn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove specific word from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527273/remove-specific-word-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
select replace(
          replace('I bought Apple , Banana , Orange and Mango', 'Apple'),
      'Banana') 
from dual;
```

or

```
declare
  my_string varchar2(50) := 'I bought Apple , Banana , Orange and Mango';
begin
  my_string := replace(replace(my_string, 'Apple'), 'Banana');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use REGEXP_REPLACE to avoid chaining multiple replace functions together.

`SELECT 
REGEXP_REPLACE(my_string, 'Apple|Banana', '') 
FROM 
my_table`

Answer (score 0):

```
select regexp_replace(source_string, '(^|\W)(Apple|Banana)(\W|$)', '\1\3', 1, 0, 'i') as new_string
  from (select  'I bought Apple , Banana , Orange and Mango' as source_string 
     from dual);


NEW_STRING  
I bought  ,  , Orange and Mango
```

This code replace whole words "Apple" or "Banana" case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

i would try something like this

select replace( replace('I bought Apple , Banana , Orange and Mango', 'Apple'),'Banana') 
from dual;